# Word Stress and explanation

Tags: word-stress

1. He **telephoned** the police yesterday.

Conveys the sense that the telephone was used, rather than different medium for communication, such as a personal visit or written (email).

2. Can you show me the **diamonds**?

Emphasizes on the item, the diamond; it can be emerald, sapphire, ruby or what not.

3. **Paul** has gone to the theatre.

Emphasizes that is Paul who went to the theatre, not his brother nor his sister.

4. Have you heard that Marcella's won **£50,000** on the lottery?

It emphasizes the amount of money that was won.

5. I'm not doing anything this **evening**.

Stressing which part of the day, that the person speaking is not busy.

Are my explanations correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You've got it exactly right. In fact, There's a funny quirk that uses this rule with some sentences in English.

If you take the sentence:

> "I never said she stole my money."

and stress a *different* word every time, the meaning of the sentence will change. you can look at it a little more in-depth [here](http://oddline.blogspot.com/2010/10/i-never-said-she-stole-my-money-7.html).